# Question on correct way to list time in a list

Tags: time

If I am using time in a list, do I need to write it out? Is this correct?
We will leave at either 12:15, 1, 2:30, or 3:15.

Comment: The only consistency issue I see in your example is a very minor one: using "1" instead of "1:00," when all other entries in the series are expressed (numerically) as hour:minutes. But even this isn't wrong; it's just stylistically inconsistent.

Comment: "either" is usually used when there are two choices. Does the list represent multiple departure times such as a tour? If so, you would use "and" instead.